# TensorFlow and CPU

Tags: tensorflow

I got the message "The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions...etc"
According to some answers in StackOverflow, this type of message, is coming up when "old" computers are used. All hints and suggestions related to installing TensorFlow did not work for me. My PCs are ca. 8-10 years old.
**My question**: What minimum configuration of a NEW PC  (e.g. Intel, NVIDIA with GPU graphic card) is supposed to be used in order to make TensorFlow installed/working? Is any newer PC and/or notebook appropriate, independently of the Manufacturer?
I use OS Ubuntu 20.04, eventually Windows in rare cases.
Thank you
Bruno

Comment: does it say "library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine"? Might need to grab the latest dependencies

Comment: This message does not prevent you from using TensorFlow, so what is your actual problem?

Comment: TensorFlow is not working.  how-to-fix-TensorFlow-library-was-compiled-to-use-sse4-1-instructions-but-these-aren't-available-on-your-machine-aborted. all messages say that this is related to OLD PCs. Do you think that it could work on a 10-year-old PC? HOW?

Comment: I have TensorFlow installed on 3 PCs with three different  UBUNTU versions. All are updated to give the same problem as mentioned. All three PCs have between 8 and 10 years. Other people on Stakoverflow say that my computers have older CPUs. If this is not correct and considering that I have the latest TensorFlow version installed and updated all the system, what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum system and software requirement to work with tensorflow was

System requirements

- Ubuntu 16.04 or higher (64-bit)
- macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or higher (64-bit) (no GPU support)
- Windows Native - Windows 7 or higher (64-bit)
- Windows WSL2 - Windows 10 19044 or higher (64-bit)

Software requirements

- Python 3.7–3.10
- pip version 19.0 or higher for Linux (requires manylinux2010 support) and Windows. pip version 20.3 or higher for macOS.

For, more details please refer to this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements). Thank You.